# Nested forms in rails 3 error, not saving properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a scaffold Product and two models `productnumbers` and `serialnumber`.

Product.rb

```
has_one :productnumber 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :productnumber
```

Productnumber.rb

```
belongs_to :product 
has_many :serialnumbers 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :serialnumbers
```

serialnumber.rb

```
belongs_to :productnumber
```

The form shows up fine and I can input data and create or update without problems but the `serialnumber` is not saved at all. When editing the product, the `serialnumber` field is blank however it had data when the product was created.

Only the `product` and `productnumber` are saved but `serialnumber` isn't saved.

Rails doesn't give an error that the `serialnumber` isn't saving. Any help how to save the `serialnumber` that is part of `productnumber`?

Comment: please show us your view code for the form, and your create action in the controller.

Comment: @BenMiller, I'm new to stackoverflow..eventually I fixed the problem, but now I have a new prob I'll upload the controller model and form

Comment: Did you remember to add the attr_accessible to your models?

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /customers
  # GET /customers.json
  def index
    @customers = Customer.find(:all, :include=> [:continent, :paymethod])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customers }
    end
  end

  # GET /customers/1
  # GET /customers/1.json
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id], :include=> [:continent, :paymethod])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customer }
    end
  end

  # GET /customers/new
  # GET /customers/new.json
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    @continents = Continent.find :all
    @paymethods = Paymethod.find :all
    @customer.build_company



    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @customer }
    end
  end


 # GET /customers/1/edit
  def edit
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @continents = Continent.find :all
    @paymethods = Paymethod.find :all

  end

  # POST /customers
  # POST /customers.json
  def create
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    @continents = Continent.find :all
    @paymethods = Paymethod.find :all


    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @customer, status: :created, location: @customer }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /customers/1
  # PUT /customers/1.json
  def update
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
        format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /customers/1
  # DELETE /customers/1.json
  def destroy
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @customer.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to customers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```